# Confusion on notion of $L$-smoothness

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization, convex-analysis, banach-spaces, smooth-functions

I have recently been reading about optimization and have come across two (seemingly different) notions of "L-smoothness".  Let me record them now; let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space and $f:H \rightarrow (-\infty,\infty)$ be Fréchet differentiable and fix $L>0$.

> [L-Smoothness - Definition 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4320397/can-l-smooth-l0-convex-function-to-be-non-differentiable) $f$ is called *L-smooth* if: for every $x_1,x_2\in H$
> $$
> \frac{L}{2}\|\cdot\|_H^2 - f \mbox{is convex}.
> $$

here is the second definition

> [L-Smoothness - Definition 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4079634/gradient-based-bound-on-an-l-smooth-strongly-convex-function) $f$ is called *L-smooth* if its Fréchet derivative $\nabla f$ is $L$-Lipschtiz.

Why/hpw are these two equivalent?

Out of curiosity: How do things generalize to separable reflexive Banach spaces?

Comment: I believe the first is usually referred to as strong convexity (albeit what I have seen is that $x \mapsto f(x)-{\mu \over 2} \|x\|^2$ is convex).

Comment: @copper.hat Yes exactly, somehow strong convexity is the lower-bound version of L-smoothness

Comment: Both are equivalent. See the book of Bauschke & Combettes, Thm 18.15